Как правильно в этом тексте: сможешь или можешь?
Сегодня вечером сможешь те задания удалить?

Как правильно: сможешь или можешь? И почему
P.S. в конце после И почему нужно поставить точку или вопросительный знак?

можешь - это просьба, сможешь - это сумеешь.

Правильно:
Сегодня вечером сможешь те задания удалить?
Пояснение

В словаре глаголы отличают  по виду (сов. или несов. вид) и времени (отнесенность к настоящему или будущему) в двух значениях: (1) быть/оказаться в состоянии, (2) получить/иметь возможность. В нашем случае это сов. вид и будущее время (не сейчас, а сегодня вечером).

По поводу оказаться в состоянии особых сомнений нет, если только голова заболит. А по поводу возможности приходится сомневаться: будет ли доступ в Сеть, будет ли свободное время.

И разумеется, это вопрос, а не утверждение.

Что касается просьбы, то ее лучше выразить грамматически (так надежнее): Сегодня вечером ты смог бы те задания удалить?


Или даже так: Сегодня вечером ты не смог бы те задания удалить?
1. МОЧЬ,  нсв. (св. смочь). с инф. 1. Быть в 
состоянии, в силах что-л. сделать. Больной может 
говорить. Кто-л. не мог встать. Спортсмен мог 
установить рекорд. Трактора могут вспахать это поле 
за день. 2. Иметь возможность что-л. делать, 
получив согласие, разрешение и т.п., преодолев что- 
л. мешающее этому. Наконец, она могла увидеть 
происходящее. Посетители могли остаться в комнате 
на несколько часов. Выздоравливающий мог теперь 
ходить по палате. 3. Быть способным, уметь что-л. 
делать. Кто-л. может петь, чинить телевизор, 
собирать двигатели. Он мог метко стрелять. 

СМОЧЬ,  св. (нсв. мочь). (с инф.). Оказаться в 
состоянии, в силах сделать что-л. Сможешь помочь 
мне? Смогу поработать вместо тебя. Смогу перевести 
этот текст. Сделаю всё, что смогу. // Получить 
возможность сделать что-л. Смогу прийти вовремя. Не 
смогу проводить тебя. Смогу заняться этим делом 
только через месяц.     


 


Я ввел правку, чтобы можно было легче читать текст. Если вы против, можете откатить правку.

Серж,  спасибо за голос и внимание к ответу. Вам не очень нравится мое оформление, поэтому я объясню свой подход. Мне кажется важным четко разделить поле ответа на две части: (1) оригинальный ответ участника, где указано правильное решение и дано его объяснение (ведь именно это особенно важно); (2) использованные справочные материалы (цитирование правил, словари, примеры и т.д.)  Иногда ответ почти весь состоит  из одних справочных текстов. // Серый фон и мелкий шрифт дают такую возможность, кроме того,  эти материалы не для того, чтобы их внимательно читать, а чтобы бегло просматривать.

Если словарь, то у меня толковый словарь Кузнецова, а на правила я обычно даю ссылки.  // Что касается самого оформления, то мне оно кажется красивым и удобным, хотя не всем нравится.  Но это мой стиль, такая своеобразная «эстетика». Наши участники использует разное оформление,  какие-то стандартные приемы для разделения текста (вертикальные полосы,  точки-звёздочки , голубенький цвет  т.д.).  Но четкого деления на зоны у них все равно нет, или я его не вижу)  Вот такое противостояние)

Шарон, дело не в том, что мне не нравится, а в том, что текст не виден полностью.

Серж, система сама меняет текст.  Я стараюсь, чтобы все было видно сразу.

Как правильно: сможешь или можешь?
Оба варианта можно использовать.
Почему?
В данном контексте при использовании глагола "сможешь" смысл такой, что ставится под вопрос возможность совершения данным человеком удаления, то есть может ли он удалить вообще.
При использовании глагола "можешь" такого нет, то есть понятно, что человек может это сделать, его просто спрашивают, сделает ли он это.
в конце после И почему нужно поставить точку или вопросительный знак?
Зависит от контекста: если вопрос (кто-то спрашивает, сможет ли человек удалить те задания), то вопросительный знак; если утверждение (кто-то говорит, что человек сможет удалить те задания; это такой скрытый приказ), то точка.
